# HTML video element to base64

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using html video tag  `<video playsinline autoplay></video>`.
Now using the canvas I display a image on the page

```
canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

My requirement is that I want to convert that image to base64 and call an API.
I tried using

```
canvas.toDataURL
```

This returns the base64 string with `data:image/png;base64,` pre appended to it.

My questions are

- Other than using string functions is there a clean way to correct the steam
- Is there a better way to send the image to API in base64 format?

Comment: maybe i don't understand, you have a requirement and you have fulfilled it. toDataURL() will return the image in base64 as you want it..

Comment: @bitten toDataURL() returns the stream but it appends "data:image/png;base64," to the final result. My question, is there a way other than string functions so that I can remove the appended string.


My second question , is there a better approach then what I have done??

Comment: i don't know why you want the current image from a video, but this is an okay way to do it. however, why do you to remove the first 3 parts from the data url?

Comment: I want to do this for face recognition, simply capturing the face, convert it to base 64, send it to an API which detects the face. I want to remove first three parts because the API expects the base64 string without these parts.

Comment: Are you sure the external API does not require the preamble which identifies the image type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canvas.toDataURL.slice('data:image/png;base64,')[1]` should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.